# I am not getting the app crashed in the C2DM registering process?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

My app gets crashed when its in the process of registering.I have tried many possible fixes for this one but no hope.I have used php in the server side.Any help on it,the below is the code I have added in it.

```
1.In the Main Activity
```

C2DMessaging.register(this, "tesyin123@gmail.com");

2.In the C2DMessaging class

public static void register(Context context, String senderId) 
{

Intent registrationIntent = new Intent(REQUEST_REGISTRATION_INTENT);

```
    registrationIntent.setPackage(GSF_PACKAGE);
    registrationIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_APPLICATION_PENDING_INTENT,PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));

    registrationIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SENDER, senderId);
    context.startService(registrationIntent);
    // TODO: if intent not found, notification on need to have GSF
}
```

---

My Manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.requestec.push.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />    
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="com.notify.AndroidNotification"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".C2DMReceiver" android:enabled="true" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.kk.push" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Receive registration ids -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.kk.push" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

</application>
```

I am not sure what I am missing in this I have tried all possible means,or am I missing any basic thing here.Thanks

Comment: Can you include the error message that you got (using DDMS)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I got 11-10 15:29:50.443: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION cat=[com.kk.push] (has extras) } to com.kk.push requires com.kk.push.permission.C2D_MESSAGE due to sender com.google.android.gsf (uid 10023)

Comment: And also 11-10 16:01:07.353: ERROR/C2DMRegistrar(188): [C2DMReg] handleRequest caught java.io.IOException: SSL shutdown failed: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a permission problem.

Assuming your Main Activity is called Main.java, and you have a class C2DMReceiver (extending C2DMBaseReceiver, handling onError and onMessage), your AndroidManifest should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kk.push" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<permission
    android:name="com.kk.push.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.kk.push.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Main" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".C2DMReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"></action>
            <category android:name="com.kk.push" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

</application>
```